# No audio after power loss

Tags: windows-7, audio, power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 no sound coming out of the speaker](https://superuser.com/questions/492748/windows-7-no-sound-coming-out-of-the-speaker)

There was a power loss in my street while the PC is Turned on, when I rebooted it there are no longer sounds coming out of my computer. added info,

I tested the speaker in another unit(in my laptop, and it is working)

I have opened the device manager to see if can recognize the device.

[image]

Next The speaker logo in my taskbar is showing properly

[image]

I tried reinstalling the driver and it still does not work.

How would I fix this issue?